# mysqld won't start, /etc/default/rcS missing in Angstrom

Tags: linux, mysql

When I attempt to start mysqld, it gives me the following error:

```
./mysqld: line 3: /etc/default/rcS: No such file or directory
```

I want to run a mysql server on angstrom linux.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Does the file /etc/default/rcS exist? Or can you access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by commenting out the following line from my /etc/init.d/mysqld file:

```
. /etc/default/rcS
```

This is a quick fix I'm guessing, I am not sure what that file does so I don't know the implications of this action, but the mysql server is now working ok!

Answer (score -2):

Your system is missing the file. Apparently it's part of the 'initscripts' package. You can attempt installing it with "sudo apt-get install initscripts". If it's been a while since updates: "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade", but maybe just the update will work. If none of that works, find one online that's suitable for your system and create it manually.

Comment: Ångström doesn't use apt.

Comment: Then use yum. You get the idea.

Comment: The idea is still wrong. That file doesn't and shouldn't exist on an Ångström system.

Comment: Just the update won't work definitely as it is just downloading list of packages